# Go: Print each element in slice on new line with html/template

Tags: go

How do I print "apple", "orange", and "pear" on a new line?

GO:

```
const titlepage = `
<html>
<h1>{{ .Title}}</h1>
<h1>{{ range $i := .Body}}{{$i}}{{end}}</h1>
</html>
`
type tp struct {
    Title string
    Body []string
}

func Read() ([]string) {
    a := []string{"apple", "orange", "pear"}
    return a
}

func main() {
    as := tp{Title: "Hello", Body: Read()}
    t := template.Must(template.New("Tele").Parse(titlepage))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, as)
}
```

Current output:

```
<html>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>appleorangepear</h1>
</html>
```

The code on Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/yhyfcq--MM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newline characters from the template will be copied into the result. If you want a newline after `{{$i}}`, you just need to add one.

Edit: If you want a newline to appear in the web browser, you need to use an HTML element like `<br/>`, or put your items in a `<li>` (list). I added a `<br/>` to the code.

http://play.golang.org/p/1G0CIfhb8a

```
const titlepage = `
<html>
<h1>{{ .Title}}</h1>
<h1>{{ range $i := .Body}}{{$i}}<br/>
{{end}}</h1>
</html>
`
type tp struct {
    Title string
    Body []string
}

func Read() ([]string) {
    a := []string{"apple", "orange", "pear"}
    return a
}

func main() {
    as := tp{Title: "Hello", Body: Read()}
    t := template.Must(template.New("Tele").Parse(titlepage))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, as)
}
```

Comment: strangely, this works on playground but doesn't work on my actual code though.

Comment: @user3918985 That's probably because you're looking at the HTML in a web browser. Newlines in HTML are treated the same as spaces. You probably want to insert a `<br/>` element instead of a newline.